# Libgdx Emoji Support

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my multiplayer game I've a chat system. I'd like to add emoji support, but I haven't find any way to do that.
To display the chat messages I use labels with a bitmapfont font. 
I think that I need to create a bitmapfont of a font that support emoji, am I right ?
Any hints please ? Thanks

Comment: That's exactly right. You can use the gdx-tools Heiro app to do it, or BMFont. Or you can use ShoeBox (http://renderhjs.net/shoebox/bitmapFont.htm) to create a font out of your own drawings.

Comment: Did you succeed on displaying emojis? If you did can you answer your own question?

Comment: Please update this answer if you solved the problem of displaying emojis